# How to turn a list into a list of DropdownMenuItems in a DropdownMenu in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently trying to show a list of EventType (custom class) objects as DropdownMenuItems in a DropdownMenu.

The code I'm trying is:

```
DropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
                ) {
                    items(plannerViewModel.eventTypeList) { eventType ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                            TypeOfEvent(eventType.color, eventType.name, openDialog)
                        }

                    }
                }
```

The problem is the *items()* function is not being recognized and I don't know how else it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`items` is for `LazyColumn`. It doesn't exist on `DropdownMenu`.

You can just use a for loop in this case

```
plannerViewModel.eventTypeList.forEach { eventType ->
   DropdownMenuItem(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is syntax of Drop Down menu.There is no scope to add items in syntax.

```
@Composable
fun DropdownMenu(
    expanded: Boolean,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    offset: DpOffset = DpOffset(0.dp, 0.dp),
    properties: PopupProperties = PopupProperties(focusable = true),
    content: @Composable @ExtensionFunctionType ColumnScope.() -> Unit
): Unit
```

If you want to add multiple items than you can use for loop like below.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun DropdownDemo() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val items = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
    val disabledValue = "B"
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)) {
        Text(items[selectedIndex],modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().clickable(onClick = { expanded = true }).background(
            Color.Gray))
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(
                Color.Red)
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                    selectedIndex = index
                    expanded = false
                }) {
                    val disabledText = if (s == disabledValue) {
                        " (Disabled)"
                    } else {
                        ""
                    }
                    Text(text = s + disabledText)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```